# Run resharper inspections on git pull request changes only

Tags: c#, git, visual-studio, resharper, pull-request

I am trying to automate the discovery of code issues in a pull request.

Currently, when I review a pull request, I checkout the affected branch, I open the solution in Visual Studio and look out for resharper warnings. Then I use that info to comment on the pull request. Checking out the branch is no problem but opening VS and opening each file affected in the pull request it time consuming.

So I am trying to somehow get resharper to only analyze the changes in the pull request and nothing more. I know resharper sometimes needs more context to do its thing correctly, but perhaps it could at least point at some warnings. 
I haven't found a way of doing this. Is it possible?

Comment: Have you looked into [ReSharper Command Line Tools](https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/features/command-line.html)?

Comment: @DanWilson yes i have and didn't find a solution there.

Comment: Only inspecting the files in the PR is insufficient. A code analysis must be performed within the context of a solution because of dependencies (e.g. other classes, interfaces, extension methods). I'd bet $0.02 that Jetbrains support will tell you the same.

Comment: I've written a blog post about that (https://blog.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2016/10/04/establishing-a-zero-warning-policy-with-resharpers-solution-wide-analysis/). You just need to configure your CI build to also trigger for pull requests. Haven't done that, but it should be possible.

Comment: Hi @balanikas, Did you find solution for this, I am looking for something similar..